# Use Zabbix web scenario status for notification

Tags: notifications, zabbix, scenarios

I've created a web scenario with three steps within my zabbix installation.
In case of an error I want to get a more detailed information about the error in the notification.
I'm getting this:

```
PROBLEM: www.mywebsite.tld.Fail : Failed step of scenario www.mywebsite.tld.
```

In the status window of the web scenarios I'm getting the information:

```
step "Product Page" [3 of 3] failed: required pattern not found
```

How can I send the text of the web scenario status into the notification?

Normally it shouldn't be such a big problem, the text is already available in the status text.
Is there a macro for this text?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to implement the notifications is to configure triggers on [the items created from web scenarios](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring/items) and relative steps. The item that holds the "required pattern not found" string is "Last error message of scenario" : web.test.error[Scenario].

Comment: That's where I'm getting the "not very chatty" answer from Zabbix.
I need the more detailed answer e.g. "failed: required pattern not found", the trigger doesn't give me this information.

Comment: Updated the answer to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can't see web output in web check.
But you can create new Zabbix item web.page.get[host,,] and then you will see web output in item history.